# Form submit returns empty data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using PHP Framework CodeIgniter.

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open('login/connect'); ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Username', 'username'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'username', 'name'=>'username')); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_label('Password', 'password'); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo form_password(array('id'=>'password', 'name'=>'password')); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Valider'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

When I try to submit this page it goes to: http://mywebsite.com/admin/index.php/login/connect

**Controller**

class Login extends CI_Controller {

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}

function connect()
{
    $username= $this->input->post('username');
    $password=$this->input->post('password');
    echo $username.', '.$password;
}
```

}

**HTML**

```
<div id="login">
    <div id="login-inner">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form action="http://myswebsite.com/admin/index.php/login/connect" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">                    
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="username">Username</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username"  /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"  /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="login_submit" value="Valider"  /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it returns an empty array.

Can anyone suggest a method to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: you didnt specified the method, so it should be a get request

Comment: Show your Controller.

Comment: @oPi you don't need to specified method in codeigniter, Its `post` by default. Check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: why you are including `.php` extension? `$this->load->view('login.tpl.php');`

Comment: @jogesh_pi didnt know. Sorry about the mistake so

Comment: Try setting it to get and check if the parameters are being forwarded. Or use the console of your browser, to trace the request.

Comment: @DainisAbols
identified the error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795982/form-submit-returns-empty-data?noredirect=1#answer-26796494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identified the issue.
It was related to the website url, and there was an unwanted 301 redirect when the form submits. 
Reference: [$this->input->post() always returning FALSE, due to an unwanted 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007928/this-input-post-always-returning-false-due-to-an-unwanted-301)

Answer (score 0):

I think he is using CodeIgniter, so the form_open() will place the method="post" automatically. Please can you share the output HTML of the form?

Check that you aren't redirecting your request, or the post variables will be resetted.
Try print_r instead of var_dump...

Comment: Hello, I've tried print_r and it doesn't worked (still getting empty data).

Comment: After capturing the request sent I got the following from the header:
Status Code:301 Moved Permanently
Is this the issue? If yes how to avoid this (is a good tutorial available for this)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Status Code 301 represents a permanent redirect. It should be the problem. Track your request and understand "where" the redirect is. When a redirect happens the POST variables are resetted. You should see your $_POST just before the redirect. I'm sorry but i'm not really experienced with CodeIgniter, but i think the problem is right there.

Answer (score 0):

don't use $_POST
 Try using

```
$username= $this->input->post('username');
$password=$this->input->post('password');
```

Comment: Yes, correct method is `$this->input->post()` but `$_POST` will also working. If OP don't get output throght `$_POST` then same happen with `$this->input->post()`

Comment: @jogesh_pi 
After capturing the request sent I got the following from the header: Status Code:301 Moved Permanently Is this the issue? If yes how to avoid this (is a good tutorial available for this)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jogesh_pi
Also I've updated my code to the method mentioned above.

Comment: @nikhil take a look on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007928/this-input-post-always-returning-false-due-to-an-unwanted-301

Comment: @jogesh_pi
Thanks, identified the issue.
It is related to an unwanted redirection.

Answer (score 0):

**Enter folowing class after parent::__construct();**

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
```